# Sleeve isn't being weighted correctly when parenting to rig

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have a model that has an arm with a short sleeve on it.  At the moment, the clothing and body are all part of the same mesh (the attached images are using a simplified version of my setup).

I'm trying to rig my character using rigify.  After generating the rig, I parent my mesh to the new rig by pressing Ctrl-P and select Armature Deform with Automatic Weights.  While this does bind the arm part of my model correctly, it does not seem to affect the sleeve.

How do I bind my sleeve?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: automatic weight often fails to weigh correctly, so you need to give some corrections in Weight Paint mode or with the Assign button under the vertex group list

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.  By adding some extra control bones specifically for the sleeve, I was able to get it to bind with useful weights.